# How do I link a Website event to the activation of an or multiple LED(s)

Tags: pi-3

This is my first Question in SO ever.

This is also my first time working with the Pi.

I want to link the activation and deactivation of LEDs to specific events on websites like <20 Visitors right now or someone bought something. I DO have access to the necessary backend of these sites. I just need to know:

- Is the Pi3 the right hardware for this or should I use the Arduino or both?
- Do you have an idea on how I should start?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definelty control LEDS with the Pi - no need for an additional Arduino.

Research GPIO tutorials for ideas about how to control LEDs, for example at [the pi hut](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/27968772-turning-on-an-led-with-your-raspberry-pis-gpio-pins).